# Use QgsAbstractProviderConnection in PyQGIS (3.14)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, connection

I created a PostGIS connection named 'test_conn' and try to access it via

```
from qgis.core import QgsAbstractProviderConnection    
con = QgsAbstractProviderConnection('test_conn')
```

as described in https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsAbstractProviderConnection.html?highlight=qgsabstractproviderconnection#module-QgsAbstractProviderConnection

but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: qgis._core.QgsAbstractProviderConnection represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated
```

Is this intended behavior or a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works with this code:

```
p = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres')
con = p.connections()['test_con']
con.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mytable')
```